# Where should I practice parrying/riposting, with what, and and optimal way (controls) to do it?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I am wanting to learn how to parry people/npcs/enemies. Is there a good location to practice? What are some good starting weapons or shields I should use for both Dark Souls 2 and Scholar of the First Sin? What are some good ways to parry, with controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good location is where the monsters are weak and slow, like the forest of fallen giants. The undead are the perfect choice in my opinion. Even if you miss a lot of parry and caught of guard, your unlikely to die.

The best gear for to practice are the buckler found in the forest of fallen giants and the parrying dagger in the Lost Bastille. Equip them in the left hand to parry. They are the best for parry but have limited use outside of that.

You can find the controls for parrying here: http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Controls

*Note: I only included equipment for Dark souls 2 and not Scholar of the First Sin since I did not play it.*

Comment: Thanks for the info! Also, from what I've done so far, I've gotten three Parrying Daggers and went into the "tutorial areas" after the Things Betwixted bonfire and practiced on those undead.